# передача переменной name при наследовании

Tags: java, ооп

не пойму как присобачить "Полкана" к "большому псу"
сохраняя вызов конструктора предка.
в остальном всё работает как надо

```
public class myDog{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Dog dog1 = new Dog("Тузик", 2);
    bigDog bdog = new bigDog("Полкан", 3);
    Dog dog2 = new Dog();
    Dog dog3 = new Dog(3);
    dog1.voice();
    dog2.voice();
    dog3.voice();
    bdog.voice();
    System.out.println("всех собак: "+Dog.count);
  }
}

public class Dog {
  private int age;//возраст
  private   String name; //кличка
  static int count = 0;//количество

  public    Dog(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name; this.age = age;
    count++;
  }
  public Dog(){
    name = "щенок";
    count++;
  }
  public Dog(int age){
    name ="дворняга";
    this.age = age;
    count++;
  }
  public void   voice() {
    System.out.print("я "+name+": ");
    for(int i = 1; i <= age; i++) System.out.print("-гав");
    System.out.println();
  }
}

class bigDog extends Dog{
  bigDog (String name, int age) {
    super(name, age);
  }

  public void   voice() {
    System.out.print("я большой пёс");
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) System.out.print("-ГАВ");
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

результат:

```
я Тузик: -гав-гав
я щенок: 
я дворняга: -гав-гав-гав
я большой пёс-ГАВ-ГАВ-ГАВ-ГАВ
всех собак: 4
```

а хотелось бы:

```
я Тузик: -гав-гав
я щенок: 
я дворняга: -гав-гав-гав
я большой пёс Полкан: -ГАВ-ГАВ-ГАВ-ГАВ
всех собак: 4
```

1. у Тузика есть кличка и он лает 2 раза(по количеству лет)
2. у щенка ещё нет клички и он не умеет лаять
3. у дворняги нет клички но она лает 3 раза(по количеству лет)
4. большого пса зовут Полкан, он умеет громко лаять но не умеет считать
5. всего посчитанных собак - 4(к счастью считает не Полкан)

если ещё подробнее то:
в классе bigDog переменная name всего лишь параметр и не видна методу voice
и нельзя объявить `System.out.print("я большой пёс"+name);`

с другой стороны name необходим super для вызова конструктора предка

всем спасибо
вопрос решил
добавлением поля name

```
class bigDog extends Dog{
  private String name;
  bigDog (String name, int age){
    super(name, age);
    this.name = name;
  }

  public void   voice(){
    System.out.print("я большой пёс "+name);
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) System.out.print(" -ГАВ");
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

всё работает как и задумывалось
но с точки зрения ооп java
всё ли верно и соответствует настроению?

Comment: Можете поподробнее по "Полкана", а то не очень понятно что хотите реализовать

Comment: в классе Dog сделайте у поля name доступ public

Comment: или вернитесь к удаленному у вас варианту геттера, оставив доступ у name как private и работая с name через getName()

Comment: пробовал я геттер не получается. потому и удалил. попробую дописать проблему в ответе. щас внесу правку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

объявляйте свои классы всегда с большой буквы BigDog, MyDog

```
public class Dog {
...

/* добавить геттер*/
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

в классе BigDog в вывод добавить getName():

```
class BigDog extends Dog{
  BigDog (String name, int age) {
    super(name, age);
  }

  public void   voice() {
    System.out.print("я большой пёс " + getName() + ":");
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) System.out.print("-ГАВ");
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

и все работает:

```
я Тузик: -гав-гав
я щенок: 
я дворняга: -гав-гав-гав
я большой пёс Полкан:-ГАВ-ГАВ-ГАВ-ГАВ
всех собак: 4
```

Comment: спасибо Prahvessor. всё дело в this. в этом и была моя ошибка. теперь всё красиво как и задумывалось. не только по результату но и внешне:)

Comment: замечание по поводу "Большой буквы" принял/учту

Comment: не забывайте о неймконвеншн - это важно )))

Comment: а где можно об этом почитать/узнать поподробнее. что-бы не встревать более

Comment: добавлять еще раз поле name в классе BigDog не нужно. используйте геттер или поменяйте модификатор доступа в род. классе. если вы добавляете name в наследника - тогда вызов super избыточен, вы же не используете потом нигде age.

Comment: да спасибо. уже всё решилось. просто я в геттере забыл сделать указание на объект. вернее не догадался

Comment: начните с официалов https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html, а потом гугл в помощь

Comment: еще пишите в циклах, if-ах блоками, а не в одну строку, даже если там один оператор. это облегчает просомтр кода другим людям